# CS50 Final Project - File Upload from html.site to flask does not work due to false form method

Tags: python, html, flask, file-upload, cs50

I've been working myself through CS50 lately but now I'm struggling with my final project. One of the key elements is to allow users to upload images from an html website while the image will be further processed via an application.py. Overall I'll use flask.

Unfortunately this is where I'm already struggling. I tried all ways I could find to upload pictures and the result is always similar, when pressing the submit-button I receive an Internal Server Error message. I even copied code from youtube or forums which worked fine in the video but not in my IDE. Is it possible that the CS50 IDE blocks file uploads in general?

If not I isolate the problem to the code below and would highly appreciate if you could have a quick look. Probably it's a tiny problem I just don't get.

Code in my application.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    file = request.files["inputFile"]

    return file.filename

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Code in the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

    <head>
        FILE UPLOAD EXAMPLE
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>File Input</h1>
            <form method="POST" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputFile">File input</label>
                    <input type="file" name="inputFile">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
```

I tried to isolate the problem and one thing I found is that the form always returns "GET" when the submit button is pressed while it is specifically defined in the form method that return should be "POST.

Anyhow, thank you so much for any comments in advance!

Best,
Martin

Comment: What is the error you are seeing and how your project structure looks like ? and what is your expected result from the code I can see that it just returns the file name which is submitted.

Comment: Hi Shakeel, thanks for helping. In the browser I see a simple "500 Internal Server Error", in my terminal a 404.

Answer (score 0):

It works when you have `templates` directory in your project structure.

```
myproject/
    __init__.py
    app.py
    templates/
        index.html
```

This is because `Flask`'s default template path is `templates`.
if you want to change it to something else  for ex 'my_templates' then you should override it while creating app.

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='my_templates')
```

Btw there is no real DB/file store code return so it will just return you the filename as response.

Comment: Thanks for the description but I'm actually running this exact structure. The application.py file is in the project folder. This folder also has a sub-folder /templates, in there I'm storing the index.html